# GetDiskFreeSpaceEx with NULL Directory Name failing

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to use GetDiskFreeSpaceEx in my C++ win32 application to get the total available bytes on the 'current' drive. I'm on Windows 7.

I'm using this sample code: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231497

And it works! Well, almost. It works if I provide a drive, such as:

```
...

szDrive[0] = 'C'; // <-- specifying drive
szDrive[1] = ':';
szDrive[2] = '\\';
szDrive[3] = '\0';

pszDrive = szDrive;

...

fResult = pGetDiskFreeSpaceEx ((LPCTSTR)pszDrive,
        　　　                  (PULARGE_INTEGER)&i64FreeBytesToCaller,
        　　　                  (PULARGE_INTEGER)&i64TotalBytes,
                               (PULARGE_INTEGER)&i64FreeBytes);
```

fResult becomes `true` and i can go on to accurately calculate the number of free bytes available.

The problem, however, is that I was hoping to not have to specify the drive, but instead just use the 'current' one. The docs I found online ([Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364937%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) state:

> *lpDirectoryName [in, optional]*
>
> A directory on the disk. If this parameter is **NULL**, the function uses the root of the current disk.

But if I pass in NULL for the Directory Name then GetDiskFreeSpaceEx ends up returning `false` and the data remains as garbage.

```
fResult = pGetDiskFreeSpaceEx (NULL,
        　　　                  (PULARGE_INTEGER)&i64FreeBytesToCaller,
        　　　                  (PULARGE_INTEGER)&i64TotalBytes,
                               (PULARGE_INTEGER)&i64FreeBytes);

//fResult == false
```

Is this odd? Surely I'm missing something? Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT**

As per JosephH's comment, I did a GetLastError() call. It returned the DWORD for:

> **ERROR_INVALID_NAME 123 (0x7B)**
>
> ```
>   The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
> ```

**2nd EDIT**

Buried down in the comments I mentioned:

> I tried GetCurrentDirectory and it returns the correct absolute path, except it prefixes it with `\\?\`

Comment: call `GetLastError()` to get the detail of the error.

Comment: Hi JosephH, I've updated my answer to contain the details of `GetLastError()`

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx( NULL, &FreeBytesToCaller, &TotalBytes, &FreeBytes)` works fine on my machine (Windows 7). I'm not using `GetProcAddress` because I wouldn't expect anyone these days to run Windows 95.

Comment: strange... I also switched out my pGetDiskFreeSpaceEx pointer out for the actual GetDiskFreeSpaceEx() function call too - ie. without the GetProcAddress stuff - still didn't work...

Comment: You have a very strange version of Windows.  Don't make us guess at it.

Comment: Not making you do anything ;) Perhaps submit "you have a strange version of windows" as and answer and I might just mark it if nothing better comes along, as it seems as though it could very well be the answer...

Comment: Hans was trying to persuade you to tell us what version of Windows you're running, and if you're aware of anything strange about it (i.e., how you have it configured, software you've installed, service packs, etc.)

Comment: Note also that passing `NULL` will retrieve the free disk space for the *current* directory. What does the [`GetCurrentDirectory` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364934.aspx) report that directory to be? Is it a valid directory? What happens when you pass the result of `GetCurrentDirectory` to `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx`?

Comment: I'm on a work PC, so I'm not 100% sure what configurations may have been made (Only been here a couple weeks!). But its Win 7 Professional SP1. But, I tried `GetCurrentDirectory` and it returns the correct absolute path, except it prefixes it with `\\?\\` - I suppose that could be the issue...? not 100% sure why it's doing it yet...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> it returns the correct absolute path, except it prefixes it with `\\?\`

That's the key to this mystery.  What you got back is the name of the directory with the *native api* path name.  Windows is an operating system that internally looks *very* different from what you are familiar with winapi programming.  The Windows kernel has a completely different api, it resembles the DEC VMS operating system a lot.  No coincidence, David Cutler used to work for DEC.  On top of that native OS were originally three api layers, Win32, POSIX and OS/2.  They made it easy to port programs from other operating systems to Windows NT.  Nobody cared much for the POSIX and OS/2 layers, they were dropped at XP time.

One infamous restriction in Win32 is the value of MAX_PATH, 260.  It sets the largest permitted size of a C string that stores a file path name.  The native api permits much larger names, 32000 characters.  You can bypass the Win32 restriction by using the path name using the native api format.  Which is simply the same path name as you are familiar with, but prefixed with `\\?\`.

So surely the reason that you got such a string back from GetCurrentDirectory() is because your current directory name is longer than 259 characters.  Extrapolating further, GetDiskFreeSpaceEx() failed because it has a bug, it *rejects* the long name it sees when you pass NULL.  Somewhat understandable, it isn't normally asked to deal with long names.  Everybody just passes the drive name.

This is fairly typical for what happens when you create directories with such long names.  Stuff just starts falling over randomly.  In general there is a *lot* of C code around that uses MAX_PATH and that code will fail miserably when it has to deal with path names that are longer than that.  This is a pretty exploitable problem too for its ability to create stack buffer overflow in a C program, technically a carefully crafted file name could be used to manipulate programs and inject malware.

There is no real cure for this problem, that bug in GetDiskFreeSpaceEx() isn't going to be fixed any time soon.  Delete that directory, it can cause lots more trouble, and write this off as a learning experience.

Comment: Coming from the different end of the world (UNIX), I do wonder ... the latter has an API, `fpathconf()` - see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/pathconf.html - that can be used to query the maximum allowable pathname length within a given directory (mountpoint / junction / ...). This in addition to the `sysconf()` global query for `PATH_MAX`. Does the Windows API have something like this ?

Comment: I don't know, click the Ask Question button.

Comment: Very informative write-up Hans, I appreciate it and no doubt others will as well. So, from here I'll do what I can to pull out the Drive name and use that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure you will have to retrieve the current drive and directory and pass that to the function.  I remember attempting to use `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx()` with the directory name as `"."`, but that did not work.